# how to install anjuta 3.6 ide - 12.04 with kde

Tags: installation, command-line, anjuta

I have downloaded the file `anjuta-3.6.1.tar.xz` from here --> http://projects.gnome.org/anjuta/
now I would like to install it but I don't know how. I have looked at the `install.txt` and I have done `cd` in the program directory and then this command:

```
./configure
```

it worked, and after that it says to give `make` but it doesn't work.
Could you help me?

Here is the output

```
$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for flex... no
checking for lex... no
configure: error: flex is required
```

I think I miss also some listed libraries at http://projects.gnome.org/anjuta/downloads.html, for example GTK+. I can't find some of these libraries.

Comment: We need to see the output of `./configure` and then of `make`. If it is very long please put it into [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and tell us the url by editing your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, I would recommend you to add a PPA, but it seems there is no one available. This is my next step if a PPA is not to be found:

Just get the source of the Anjuta 3.4 debian package, change the sources to the version 3.6, and compile the package again.

From a console, get the debian package source.

```
mkdir ~/anjuta_compiling_place
cd ~/anjuta_compiling_place
apt-get source anjuta
```

Now, download the anjuta source code.

```
wget http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/anjuta/3.6/anjuta-3.6.1.tar.xz
```

If you are reading this after a while, instead of using this URL, get the latest version URL from http://www.anjuta.org/.

Rename (important for later steps!) and uncompress the downloaded source and cd into the directory:

```
mv anjuta-3.6.1.tar.xz anjuta_3.6.1.orig.tar.xz
tar xf anjuta-3.6.1.orig.tar.xz
cd anjuta-3.6.1
```

Uncompress the debian files:

```
tar xzf ../anjuta_*.debian.tar.gz
```

Install the required dependencies to compile anjuta:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep anjuta
```

Run `debchange`, and edit the first entry changing the first line with the correct version, for example:

```
anjuta (2:3.6.1-0ubuntu1) UNRELEASED; urgency=low
```

You could also add some text describing what you did, in the same fashion as all the other entries on that file. Be cautious!

Also, if you want to autosign the package, make sure your name and your e-mail are the correct ones. If you don't know what I'm talking about, just ignore it.

Now, save <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and exit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

And then compile the new package:

```
debuild
```

This could fail, but if you are lucky, after a while, you should have your new shiny debian package at `~/anjuta_compiling_place`.

Now, just click on the packages on the correct order to install them, or issue these commands:

```
cd ~/anjuta_compiling_place
sudo dpkg -i libanjuta*.deb anjuta*.deb
```

If you find any difficulties, please add a comment and I'll try to make corrections and help you. Try to be as verbose as possible (copy & paste the errors, and so).

Comment: ok thanks, I have a problem at the step "Run debchange, and edit the first entry changing the first line with the correct version, for example:" I don't understand what to do there

Comment: You run the command `debchange` and then a text editor shows up. You will recognize a lot of entries consisting on a version number, some points describing the changes of that version, an author and a date. By running `debchange` you create a new entry. Just change the version number for the correct one, save and quit.

Answer (score 2):

Type this into the Terminal to install it:

`sudo apt-get install anjuta`

Comment: yes I know, sorry I forgot to tell it. The problem is that in the repositories there is an old version. I have downloaded a new one :)

Answer (score 0):

For most software it is not necessary to download and compile it yourself. You can easily install those packages from the **Ubuntu repositories**. You can use *Add/Remove Programs* or just type `sudo apt-get install anjuta` on the command line.

Comment: yes I know, sorry I forgot to tell it. The problem is that in the repositories there is an old version. I have downloaded a new one :)